# Data structure compatibility issue between foreach parallelisation and tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, parallel-foreach

I have found that the function `pec::predictSurvProb` works fine in a `foreach` loop when using objects of class `data.frame` but not when using objects of class `tbl_df` which appears to be the default `tibble` class produced when using `dplyr` manipulation. I get an error message which wasn't much help: **Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double]."**

The solution was to convert my data to class `data.frame` from `tbl_df` but I am curious as to why this problem occurs. It looks like tibbles are actually not extensions of data frames because they behave differently and this behaviour is incompatible with other R packages.

I am unsure if this type of incompatibility is well-documented but I found a brief discussion here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2017q3/001896.html

I have tried to show the issue in the following `repex`:

```
# repex
library(survival)
library(pec)
library(dplyr)
library(doParallel) 

data("lung") # example data set
class(lung) # which is class data.frame

lung2 <- lung %>%
group_by(inst) %>%
mutate(T_MAX = max(time)) %>%
ungroup() # use dplyr to create a new variable T_MAX

class(lung2) # lung2 is of class tibble (tbl_df)

lung3 <- lung %>%
group_by(inst) %>%
mutate(T_MAX = max(time)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
as.data.frame() # same dplyr manipulation but coercion to class data.frame at the end

class(lung3) # lung3 is of class data.frame

# create identical Cox PH models using the different data sets lung2 and lung3
mdl_lung2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ inst + age + sex,
               data = lung2,
               x = TRUE)

summary(mdl_lung2)

mdl_lung3 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ inst + age + sex,
               data = lung3,
               x = TRUE)

summary(mdl_lung3)

# predictSurvProb function works and output is the same
predictSurvProb(mdl_lung2, newdata = lung2, times = 365)
predictSurvProb(mdl_lung3, newdata = lung3, times = 365)

# initiate parallelisation
cores <- detectCores() 
registerDoParallel(cores = cores) 
cat("No. of cores initiated for parallel processing:", getDoParWorkers()) 

# foreach application does not work using lung2
lung2$P_TEST <- foreach(j=1:nrow(lung2),
                      .combine = c) %dopar% { # Return a vector
                        predictSurvProb(mdl_lung2, lung2[j, ], times = lung2[j, "T_MAX"])
                      }

# but does using lung3
lung3$P_TEST <- foreach(j=1:nrow(lung3),
                   .combine = c) %dopar% { # Return a vector
                     predictSurvProb(mdl_lung3, lung3[j, ], times = lung3[j, "T_MAX"])
                   }

summary(lung3$P_TEST)
```

Comment: Without having looked at the package code I’d say that you diagnosed the issue correctly, and that the package relies on specific `data.frame` behaviour that most people agree was a mistake. The best course of action would therefore be if the package authors fixed the package to not rely on that behaviour. As a side-effect it would then work with tibbles as well (which, strictly speaking, break the inheritance contract of `data.frame` — but for a very good reason).

Comment: This has nothing to do with `foreach`. Compare `lung2[1, "T_MAX"]`  and `lung3[1, "T_MAX"]`. The issue is the different default of the `drop` parameter in `[.data.frame` and `[.tbl_df`. @KonradRudolph It is not a package issue, it's a user error.

Comment: Btw. just use `%do%`  instead of `%dopar%` and you'll see an informative error message.

Comment: @Roland Oh right, indeed.

Comment: @Roland If it is a user error then it is one that is not obvious to me. The default `drop` parameter differences don't seem like something that would be known by all R users. How come the `predictSurvProb` function works fine on both `lung2` and `lung3` outside of the foreach loop but not within?The error message is the same for both `%do%` and `%dopar%` by the way. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Seanosapien It works outside the loop because outside the loop you’re not subsetting your `lungX` data sets, you’re passing them to `coxph` in their entirety.

Comment: In fact, specifying `drop = TRUE` within the `[ , ]` makes everything work fine also. @Roland your answer makes sense now so thanks again.